# How do I generate a specific date such as the 13th of March

Tags: php

I have been using the following code to generate a date.

```
$datejoined = strip_tags(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 day")));
```

How would I generate a specific date for April 13th?

Comment: From the manual: `echo strtotime("10 September 2000");`

Comment: Why [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

Comment: Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and its friends.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` can generate date date from almost any line of text.
`strtotime('April 13')` is okay for April 13 in current year. Test it with the following line of code:

```
  print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('April 13'));
```

But personally I would suggest you to use much faster function `mktime()`:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 13); // 0:00:00, 4th month, 13 day, [current year].
```

Comment: It's complicated. if you have already know the month and day, why not use `date('Y-04-13 H:i:s')` ?

Comment: If you need the date it as (string), you don't need date() at all, just write it as flat string.
But if you need it as timestamp (integer) — mktime() is the best way to generate required date.

Comment: `mktime()` was a good tool when `[current year]` was 2009 (and current version of PHP was 4). It's 2019 now and the old date & time functions are just a way to write verbose and difficult to understand code. Use the [date and time classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: axiac, why not just suggest other code, less "verbose" and less "difficult to understand" or maybe more easy to use than just simple `mktime()` line? Or maybe DateTime class is faster than `mktime()`?

Comment: thanks guys for the suggestion and I will try both ways to see which is easier

Comment: I have been doing that strtotime for 1 month etc but didn't now you can add the month such as April 13